# set a GUI Texture to Fit a UI panel

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a panel with a GUI texture is been created by code as this :

```
GUITexture background=gameObject.AddComponent<GUITexture>();
```

How can i make this GUITexture to Fit a Panel inside a canvas No matter what the screen width or height are i am trying this code but it does not work :

```
GUITexture background=gameObject.AddComponent<GUITexture>();
Image img = gameObject.GetComponent<Image>();
Vector3 posStart=Camera.Main.WorldtoScreenPoit(img.RectTransform.anchorMin.x,img.RectTransform.anchorMin.y,0);
Vector3 posEnd=Camera.Main.WorldtoScreenPoit(img.RectTransform.anchorMax.x,img.RectTransform.anchorMax.y,0);

int widthX = (int)(posEnd.x - posStart.x);
int widthY = (int)(posEnd.y - posStart.y);

GUITexture.PixelInset= new Rect(posStart.x,posStart.y,widthX,widthY);
```

I am sorry if any syntax error may occur as i didn't copy and past the code 
the code that i am using should scale the gui layer based on the UI panel `RectTransform` but this is how the view is looking like

[image]

the canvas is set to fit the screen resolution (width and height) , but as you can see th GUITexture is not fitting the UI Panel ,what i am doing wrong

PS: The GUITexture is being used as a WebcamTexture , i am using a GUITexture over a panel for the sake of the responsiveness between multiple devices, i was using a plane , but i did not know how to resize it based on screen width and height

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is basically emulate in code the parameters applied by the Editor when you center an object by holding ALT and SHIFT.

This should be achieved by:

- X, Y Position set to 0.5;
- X, Y Scale set to 1.0;
- Pixel Inset values set to 0.